# no such column: EPF (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR) Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

This is my second time building a database and everything looks perfectly fine compared to my first database that works, but when I run it I get this error:

```
Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: EPF (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Id, Name, Age, PCB, EPF, SOCSO, EIS, GrossSalary, NetSalary, EmployerEPF, EmployerSOCSO, EmployerEIS FROM payrollTable
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0
  at Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.Query (System.String table, System.String[] columns, System.String selection, System.String[] selectionArgs, System.String groupBy, System.String having, System.String orderBy) [0x000e6] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0
  at PayrollParrots.Helper.PayrollHelper.GetPayrollList (Android.Content.Context context) [0x0007e] in /Users/danyalqureshi/Projects/PayrollParrots/PayrollParrots/Helper/PayrollHelper.cs:103
  at PayrollParrots.MainActivity.BindData () [0x00001] in /Users/danyalqureshi/Projects/PayrollParrots/PayrollParrots/MainActivity.cs:93
  at PayrollParrots.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00055] in /Users/danyalqureshi/Projects/PayrollParrots/PayrollParrots/MainActivity.cs:35
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.4(intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: EPF (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT Id, Name, Age, PCB, EPF, SOCSO, EIS, GrossSalary, NetSalary, EmployerEPF, EmployerSOCSO, EmployerEIS FROM payrollTable
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
  at at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1294)
  at at crc642ab3dab37b1a36d6.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at at crc642ab3dab37b1a36d6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
  at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
  at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
  at at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is my Database code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;
using PayrollParrots.Model;
using Android.Database;
namespace PayrollParrots.Helper
{
    public class PayrollHelper
    {
        private const string TableName = "payrollTable";
        private const string ColumnID = "Id";
        private const string ColumnName = "Name";
        private const string ColumnAge = "Age";
        private const string ColumnPCB = "PCB";
        private const string ColumnEPF = "EPF";
        private const string ColumnSOCSO = "SOCSO";
        private const string ColumnEIS = "EIS";
        private const string ColumnGross = "GrossSalary";
        private const string ColumnNet = "NetSalary";
        private const string ColumnEmployerEPF = "EmployerEPF";
        private const string ColumnEmployerSOCSO = "EmployerSOCSO";
        private const string ColumnEmployerEIS = "EmployerEIS";
        public const string CreateQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TableName + " ( "
            + ColumnID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
               + ColumnName + " TEXT,"
               + ColumnAge + " INTEGER,"
               + ColumnPCB + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnEPF + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnSOCSO + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnEIS + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnGross + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnNet + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnEmployerEPF + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnEmployerSOCSO + " BLOB,"
               + ColumnEmployerEIS + " BLOB)";


        public const string DeleteQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableName;

        public PayrollHelper()
        {
        }

        public static void InsertPayrollData(Context context, Payroll payroll)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = new DataStore(context).WritableDatabase;
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.Put(ColumnName, payroll.Name);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnAge, payroll.Age);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnPCB, payroll.PCB);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnEPF, payroll.EPF);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnSOCSO, payroll.SOCSO);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnEIS, payroll.EIS);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnGross, payroll.GrossSalary);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnNet, payroll.NetSalary);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnEmployerEPF, payroll.EmployerEPF);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnEmployerSOCSO, payroll.EmployerSOCSO);
            contentValues.Put(ColumnEmployerEIS, payroll.EmployerEIS);

            db.Insert(TableName, null, contentValues);
            db.Close();
        }

        public static Payroll SelectPayroll(Context context, int payrollId)
        {
            Payroll payroll;
            SQLiteDatabase db = new DataStore(context).ReadableDatabase;
            string[] columns = new string[] { ColumnID, ColumnName, ColumnAge, ColumnPCB, ColumnEPF, ColumnSOCSO, ColumnEIS, ColumnGross, ColumnNet, ColumnEmployerEPF, ColumnEmployerSOCSO, ColumnEmployerEIS };
            using (ICursor cursor = db.Query(TableName, columns, ColumnID + "=" + payrollId, null, null, null, null))
            {
                if (cursor.MoveToNext())
                {
                    payroll = new Payroll
                    {
                        Id = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnID)),
                        Name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnName)),
                        Age = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnAge)),
                        PCB = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnPCB)),
                        EPF = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEPF)),
                        SOCSO = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnSOCSO)),
                        EIS = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEIS)),
                        GrossSalary = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnGross)),
                        NetSalary = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnNet)),
                        EmployerEPF = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerEPF)),
                        EmployerEIS = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerSOCSO)),
                        EmployerSOCSO = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerEIS))
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    payroll = null;
                }
            }
            return payroll;
        }

        public static List<Payroll> GetPayrollList(Context context)
        {
            List<Payroll> payroll = new List<Payroll>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = new DataStore(context).ReadableDatabase;
            string[] columns = new string[] { ColumnID, ColumnName, ColumnAge, ColumnPCB, ColumnEPF, ColumnSOCSO, ColumnEIS, ColumnGross, ColumnNet, ColumnEmployerEPF, ColumnEmployerSOCSO, ColumnEmployerEIS };

            using (ICursor cursor = db.Query(TableName, columns, null, null, null, null, null))
            {
                while (cursor.MoveToNext())
                {
                    payroll.Add(new Payroll
                    {
                        Id = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnID)),
                        Name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnName)),
                        Age = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnAge)),
                        PCB = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnPCB)),
                        EPF = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEPF)),
                        SOCSO = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnSOCSO)),
                        EIS = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEIS)),
                        GrossSalary = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnGross)),
                        NetSalary = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnNet)),
                        EmployerEPF = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerEPF)),
                        EmployerEIS = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerSOCSO)),
                        EmployerSOCSO = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerEIS))
                    });
                }
            }
            db.Close();
            return payroll;
        }

        public static void DeletePayroll(Context context, Payroll payroll)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = new DataStore(context).WritableDatabase;
            db.Delete(TableName, ColumnName + "=? AND " + ColumnAge + "=? AND " + ColumnPCB + "=? AND " + ColumnEPF + "=? AND " + ColumnSOCSO + "=? AND " + ColumnEIS + "=? AND " + ColumnGross + "=? AND " + ColumnNet + "=? AND " + ColumnEmployerEPF + "=? AND " + ColumnEmployerSOCSO + "=? AND " + ColumnEmployerEIS + "=? OR " + ColumnID + "=" + payroll.Id, new string[] { payroll.Name });
            db.Close();
        }

        public static Payroll SelectPayroll(Context context)
        {
            Payroll payroll;
            SQLiteDatabase db = new DataStore(context).WritableDatabase;
            string[] columns = new string[] { ColumnID, ColumnName, ColumnAge, ColumnPCB, ColumnEPF, ColumnSOCSO, ColumnEIS, ColumnGross, ColumnNet, ColumnEmployerEPF, ColumnEmployerSOCSO, ColumnEmployerEIS };


            using (ICursor cursor = db.Query(TableName, columns, ColumnName + "=? AND " + ColumnAge + "=? AND " + ColumnPCB + "=? AND " + ColumnEPF + "=? AND " + ColumnSOCSO + "=? AND " + ColumnEIS + "=? AND " + ColumnGross + "=? AND " + ColumnNet + "=? AND " + ColumnEmployerEPF + "=? AND " + ColumnEmployerSOCSO + "=? AND " + ColumnEmployerEIS + "=?", new string[] { },null, null, null))
            {
                if (cursor.MoveToNext())
                {
                    payroll = new Payroll
                    {
                        Id = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnID)),
                        Name = cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnName)),
                        Age = cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnAge)),
                        PCB = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnPCB)),
                        EPF = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEPF)),
                        SOCSO = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnSOCSO)),
                        EIS = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEIS)),
                        GrossSalary = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnGross)),
                        NetSalary = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnNet)),
                        EmployerEPF = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerEPF)),
                        EmployerEIS = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerSOCSO)),
                        EmployerSOCSO = cursor.GetDouble(cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(ColumnEmployerEIS))
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    payroll = null;
                }
            }
            return payroll;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my models file:

```
namespace PayrollParrots.Model
{
    public class Payroll
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public double PCB { get; set; }
        public double EPF { get; set; }
        public double SOCSO { get; set; }
        public double EIS { get; set; }
        public double GrossSalary { get; set; }
        public double NetSalary { get; set; }
        public double EmployerEIS { get; set; }
        public double EmployerSOCSO { get; set; }
        public double EmployerEPF { get; set; }
        public Payroll()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If I delete the "ColumnEPF" and all the columns after that my code works, but when I add ColumnEPF it doesn't work. I've tried changing the name of the ColumnEPF but that doesn't work either.

@ORTUND
LIKE THIS?

[image]

Any help Appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the table schema from the database? If you need, there's a free tool to use called DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: what do you mean by a table schema?

Comment: @Ortund I added a screenshot of what I think you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating database in application, you need to upgrade database to update table.

Please check below link for reference.
https://gist.github.com/matpag/b2545cc22c8e22449cd7eaf6b4910396

You can use below query while update table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_definition;
```

Comment: I am not trying to update the table, it won't even let me create the table in the first place

Comment: its just saying that it couldn't find the column "EPF" even though I added it, and I can't find anything I did wrong

Comment: actually this worked, but I also changed the database name and table name and that fixed my problem too